# Please explain the logic behind this ruby fiber example

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, fiber

The example code is from [here](http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/22/untangling-evented-code-with-ruby-fibers/):

```
def http_get(url)
  f = Fiber.current
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get

  # resume fiber once http call is done
  http.callback { f.resume(http) }
  http.errback  { f.resume(http) }

  return Fiber.yield
end

EventMachine.run do
  Fiber.new{
    page = http_get('http://www.google.com/')
    puts "Fetched page: #{page.response_header.status}"

    if page
      page = http_get('http://www.google.com/search?q=eventmachine')
      puts "Fetched page 2: #{page.response_header.status}"
    end
  }.resume
end
```

So, in the context of the EM run block, the author's creating a fiber and running it immediately with `resume`. But, I don't understand why the `http_get` logic is structured in that way. I mean, it's taking the current fiber ( which in this case should be the one created in the EM run block ), it starts a http request which may fail or succeed, and it resumes the current fiber. Afterwards it just calls `yield` on the fiber. What exactly will be running since he is calling yield? Can someone please explain why `http_get` is written the way it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fiber is created and triggered in EventMachine
2. the goal is (a) to fetch a page and (b) work on it
3. the Fiber should be paused until the page is fetched, this is the role of `http_get`
4. `http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get` doesn't trigger anything: EventMachine needs to get the reins back, that's the role of `Fiber.yield`
5. Once EventMachine has done the job getting the page, it triggers the callback and resumes the Fiber which was stopped at `puts ...`

Clearer?

Comment: Why should the Fiber be paused? Also, the code stops at `puts "Fetched page: #{page.response_header.status}"` until the fiber gets a chance to run& complete?

Comment: to pass the hand to EventMachine

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. Since you have some EM experience, could you maybe have a quick look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663944/how-can-i-load-all-the-objects-inside-a-table-and-keep-eventmachine-responsive ? Maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a race condition? e.g. is it possible for resume to be called before yield?